# Braking with left foot is sharper than doing with right foot

Tags: braking

I am driving manual transmission cars for decades. Irrespective of whether it is a new or old car, I find the brakes are very sharp if I brake using my left foot  in par with when I brake with my right foot in the very same car.

Recently I tried this on an automatic transmission car and found the same.  I am not talking about rallying or racing technique where left foot braking is used. I am talking about normal day-to-day commuting low/medium powered cars.

I searched on Internet and on this site and all search results yield only about the left foot braking about rally/race driving only and hence I posted this question here. Being an mechanical engineer, I could not come to a logical conclusion about this phenomenon.

Comment: Hi @Narayanan - I'm afraid this question is really about driving techniques rather than anything mechanical, so it's off-topic here - but you're welcome to take it to [the pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to chat about it

Answer (score 5):

It is because you have, over years, “educated” your left foot /brain / muscle memory to hit the pedal and go to the floor ie clutch to change gear.

You now have to re-learn the use of the left foot to use the brake pedal - and yes it is possible but just takes practise...

Similar is heel and toeing where one uses the right foot to operate brake and accelerator compared to either alone